# multiply elements of two different lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data file which I have imported and form a table.

```
list1 = Flatten[Table[{relic[[i]]}, {i, 1, 5}], 1]
```

the output looks like this

```
{{4.992596228629734*^-14}, {9.985192457259468*^-14},{1.49777886858892*^-13}, {1.9970384914518936*^-13}, {2.496298114314867*^-13}}
```

I have another list

```
masslist =  Reap[For[i = 2, i <= 50, i = i + 10, Sow[i]];][[2, 1]]~Partition~1
```

output is

```
{{2}, {12}, {22}, {32}, {42}}
```

Now I want to form another table by multiplying the elements of the two lists. I used this

```
newlist =  Table[{masslist[[i, 1]], masslist[[i, 1]]*list1[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[masslist]}]
```

But that is not working. It gives an output like this

```
{{2, 2 4.992596228629734*^-14}, {12, 12 9.985192457259468*^-14}, {22, 22 1.49777886858892*^-13}, {32,32 1.9970384914518936*^-13}, {42, 42 2.496298114314867*^-13}}
```

I think is not working because of the number format of the first list. Can you please help?

Comment: `masslist = List /@ Range[2,50,10]` is the Mathematica way of doing it (not asking why you want the elements to be lists...). For me the rest works fine, you may have some conflicting definitions - try a fresh session.

Comment: Please add all the definitions (e.g. what is `relic`?) so that people can reproduce your results.

Comment: Try `Head@list1[[1,1]]` to verify that you have a `Real` number. If not, then you may need to use `ToExpression[]` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has constructs that are more powerful than C:

```
(* make up a list called relic *)
relic = Range[1, 7, 1]

(* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} *)

(* create massList *)
massList = Range[2, 50, 10]

(* {2,12,22,32,42} *)

(* multiply massList by a corresponding length of relic *)
product = massList Take[relic, Length[massList]]

(* {2,24,66,128,210} *)
```

Kind regards,
David